# rails multiple queries in index file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it normal to have multiple results in a post index.html.erb file? Lets say in the File I want to get Popular posts, and recent posts. Could I put those both In the index file or should i do something else. like this:

```
def index
 /* get recent posts */
 @News = News.all

/* get popular posts */
(popular posts code)
end
```

and in the index.html.erb file i would put the popular posts in some sort of sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this a question of where to put the logic that performs the queries, then no, they should not be in the index.html.erb. They should be in the object model. You COULD put the logic in the object controller, but its not a good practice to get into.

I'd just define some methods in the model that query the db for whatever you want to appear. I did something similar in an app I developed a few weeks ago:

```
  def self.upcoming
    Event.where('events.when > ?', Time.now).order(when: :asc)
  end
```

That class method returns all the events in my db that are scheduled to start after the current time (sort of like recent posts I guess). I call it from my index using `Event.upcoming`

Comment: could i put the logic in the post controller index function?

Comment: You could, but it's considered bad practice and I don't even think it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is common. No harm in doing it. Recent Posts and Popular Post or even its comments with its respective users can come to that action.

Comment: could i put the logic in the post controller index function?